# Can you fetch a signed download URL (Firebase Storage) alongside App Check being enforced?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When fetching a resource from the URL I obtain from the function `getDownloadURL`, I get a `401 Firebase App Check token is invalid.`. Is this the correct behavior, or is there a missing step?

At first I thought this was a CORS issue so I updated that according to the documentation, but looking closer at the response, it's clearly an App Check concern.

So in short, can you fetch a signed download URL alongside App Check being enforced? I looked high and low for some documentation related to this, but alas I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm not aware of any limit in getting download URLs while App Check is enabled, but it's hard to say more.
"Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen for the answer and how to frame my question better for next time.